# Do I always have to await on an Async method of a disposable object instead of returning its Task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Seems I fell into a massive gotcha and after hours of debugging I saw that process goes out of "using" scope in RunGame1() and the Task never completes when awaited upon.

```
async void Execute(object o)  // ICommand.Execute
{
    // fire and forget
    try
    {
        await RunGame2();  // RunGame1() fails to complete
    }
    finally
    { ... }
}

// This fails due to process going out of "using" scope and never completes
Task RunGame1()
{
    var info = new ProcessStartInfo("game.exe") { CreateNoWindow = true };
    using var process = new Process() { StartInfo = info };
    process.Start();
    return process.WaitForExitAsync();
}

// Have to await the Task inside the method
async Task RunGame2()
{
    var info = new ProcessStartInfo("game.exe") { CreateNoWindow = true };
    using var process = new Process() { StartInfo = info };
    process.Start();
    await process.WaitForExitAsync();
}
```

Is there a pattern to get around this so I can return the Task to save the compiler making an extra state machine or is it just something to be aware of?

Comment: You could return `Task<Process>`, at which point you would get rid of the `using` inside your method and let the caller dispose it.

Comment: @GSerg I would strongly advise against that; there's no reason the caller needs to know any of those implementation details, and you're forcing extra ceremony onto the call-site for no good reason; adding the `await` would be preferable

Comment: That's a good reading, if you haven't already read it: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common gotcha indeed - I've seen several bugs due to similar.

In short:

- *no*, you're not **always** required to `await` a task, and sometimes it can be actively advantageous to avoid the overhead of the async machinery - especially in tight code like file/network IO loop, ***but*** (and it is a big but)
- *if* that means you're escaping a `try`/`finally` region (which also includes `using` and `lock`, although there are other bigger problems with `lock` in `async` code), then *you need to take that into consideration*, which usually means "yes, you need to `await`"

It would be nice if there was an analyzer that spotted the `return` of a `Task[<T>]`/`ValueTask[<T>]` in a non-`async` method, **inside** such a region, as it is almost always a bug, and for the few times that it isn't (where the `finally` has nothing to do with the thing being returned) it could be suppressed.